# Fragments are not opening (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I've created a drawer menu in `MainActivity` class and I want to create new Fragment when button is clicked (it sounds simple). However when I click on button nothing happens.

My MainActivity layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/purple_500" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my `MainActivity` function for opening different Fragments looks like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setReorderingAllowed(true);

    if (position == POS_DASHBOARD) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POS_DASHBOARD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        RandomFragment randomFragment = new RandomFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, randomFragment);
    }
    else if (position == POS_MY_PROFILE) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POS_MY_PROFILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RandomFragment randomFragment = new RandomFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, randomFragment);
    }
    else if (position == POS_NEAR) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POS_NEAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RandomFragment randomFragment = new RandomFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, randomFragment);
    }
    else if (position == POS_SETTINGS) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POS_SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RandomFragment randomFragment = new RandomFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, randomFragment);
    }
    else if (position == POS_ABOUT_US) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POS_ABOUT_US", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RandomFragment randomFragment = new RandomFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, randomFragment);
    }
    else if (position == POS_LOGOUT) {
        finish();
    }

    //slidingRootNav.closeMenu();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I used Toast to find out if position is working correctly and it is. I struggle with it all day and I have no idea why it s not working

This is my RandomFragment:

```
public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_random, container, false);


        return root;
    }
}
```

and this is it's layout:

```
`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_700"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_random">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Please help me

Comment: Maybe the fragment is being inflated, but you can't feel it since the layout for the fragment is empty add some textview or some other view then try.

Comment: The fragment has completely different background color -> I ve also tried with more complicated fragment with more views in it so I would ve notice

Comment: where and how `onItemSelected` is being called?

Comment: It's not a problem too -> I know that this function works fine because of Toasts that are in it. In addition when I click on "logout" button which is on POS_LOGOUT position the finish() function is perfoming and the application is closing (what I wanted to achieved). But this awful transactionManager doesn't work at all

Comment: Add `@Override`.

Comment: `android:orientation="horizontal" ` change this to `android:orientation="vertical"`, in you main linear layout

Comment: @rahat Man ! You're the best ! so many hours .... Thanks a lot!